# Proving conditional probability statement.

Tags: statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

If X can have the value of either 0 or 1, then is it true to say that:
$$ P(Z=0|X) = P(Z=0|X=0) + P(Z=0|X=1)? $$
I tried to prove it by saying that
$$P(Z=0|(X = 0 \: OR\: 1)) = \frac {P(0 \: \cap (0 \cup 1))}{P(0 \cup 1)} = \frac{P(0 \: \cap 0)}{P(0)}+\frac{P(0 \: \cap 1))}{P(1)} = P(Z=0|X=0) + P(Z=0|X=1) $$
Is my prove wrong? or the statement from the beginning is wrong?

Comment: Or is the step from converting P(0∪1)to P(0 ) and P(1) wrong? so the statement is wrong?

Comment: $P(Z=0|X)$ is a random variable, $P(Z=0|X=0) + P(Z=0|X=1)$ is a number.